# Heroku PHP pgconnect - password authentication failed for user

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL from PHP on Heroku. For simplification I tried:

```
function pg_connection_string_from_database_url() {
    extract(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL")));
    return "user=$user password=$pass host=$host sslmode=require dbname=" . substr($path, 1);
}
$pg_conn = pg_connect(pg_connection_string_from_database_url());
```

I keep getting this error:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user
```

I've tried:

- Connecting with same credentials using Navicat: works
- Connecting to a local pgsql database using PHP: works
- Connecting with same credentials from CLI: works

This makes me think there is something that PHP should do with the password. I found some things about MD5 online, but can't find anything specific.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```
~ dzuelke$ heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.4366
~ $ php -r '
> function pg_connection_string_from_database_url() {
>     extract(parse_url(getenv("DATABASE_URL")));
>     return "user=$user password=$pass host=$host sslmode=require dbname=" . substr($path, 1);
> }
> $pg_conn = pg_connect(pg_connection_string_from_database_url());
> var_dump($pg_conn);'
resource(4) of type (pgsql link)
```

Double and triple check that your `DATABASE_URL` is correct, that it's the actual connection you want to use (versus another env var), what value `getenv("DATABASE_URL")` returns, and so forth.

Also, you're not specifying a port; so it'll use the default 5432, which might be incorrect.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm connecting from (a Heroku hobby-dev) to a postgres DB on another Heroku App (production). The code above indeed works when connecting to the local DB.

Comment: Well then your `DATABASE_URL` is maybe wrong, or you need to read from a different env var that has the right credentials?

Comment: dzuelke, could you try if its also possible to connect to that database if you run that code locally? (off course with the right DATABASE_URL var)